# Close NavigationDrawer with handler timer

Tags: android, counter, navigation-drawer, android-handler

Im developing an `Android` application which uses a `navigationDrawer`. I want the drawer to close it self after five seconds, which it does. The problem is that the `thread` is running after the `navigationDrawer` is closed. So if i close the `navigationDrawer` manually after 2 seconds, and then re-open it, it will closes it self after ~3 seconds.

What can i do to solve this problem? Iv been trying to kill the handler, but can't get it to work.

```
public void counter() {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList_Right);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList_Left);
                }
            }, 5000);
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            counter();

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private static int counterValue = 1;
private static int lastCounterValue;

public void counter(final int counter) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (lastCounterValue == counter)
                {
                  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList_Right);
                  mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList_Left);
                }
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    counterValue++;
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    lastCounterValue = counterValue;
        counter(counterValue);

    }
};
```

Comment: didn't work, the thread is still running and closes the drawer.

Comment: Hmm, maybe try to use a static boolean

Comment: Same problem as before.

Comment: Try now, I fixed mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can call [handler.removeCallbacks(Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to get rid of the pending (not jet executed) runnables. But to do so you have to modify your code a bit. Make the Handler global and make a global Runnable like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

public Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList_Right);
      mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList_Left);
    }
}
```

Now you can call them in your method like this:

```
public void counter() {

    handler.postDelayed(r, 5000); // call the runnable
}
```

In your close callback from the Drawer remove the runnable:

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

    handler.removeCallbacks(r);

    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    counter();
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem im afraid.

Comment: removeCallbacks() Dosn't kill threads that is already running, it just clears the queue. Any other options?

Comment: Remove the boolean drawerOpened.